# Async Task in loop

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a problem with AsyncTask. I want to send a query several times to my remote server, but it gives me an error every time and only one line is sent. Here is my code snippet

```
// I take the history in the local base
List <Historique> = historiqueDAO.findAll();

HistoriqueTask historiqueTask = new HistoriqueTask (this);

for (Historique historique: historiques) {
    // Request to remote server
    historiqueTask.execute ("addHistorique" + historique.toURI ()); 
}
```

Comment: which error you are getting?post logcat

Comment: are you able to compile code? HistoriqueTask historiqueTask HistoriqueTask = new (this); should be HistoriqueTask historiqueTask  = new HistoriqueTask (this);

Comment: Yes, i'm able to compile code

Comment: 08-06 07:10:03.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1304): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task is already running.

Comment: instead of running async inside loop why don't you loop inside async. in async task you already have option to send array of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AsyncTask` can be executed only once. You need to create new instance on every iteration.
Refer to "Threading Rules" in [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: So there's no way to do it?

Comment: No way to execute single instance twice

Comment: creating a new instance in loop is the solution?

Comment: Yes, also look at the comments below your question. Maybe there's a way to send an array within one request.